# Wordpress post except not working correctly with thematic theme framework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Getting the same problem as this guy in the support forum for the parent theme...
http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/excerpt-on-front-page-childtheme_override_content_init-never-called#post-16836

I ask here because no one seemed to be able to help him.

If anyone understands wordpress quite well, and has dealt with the thematic theme framework before, your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this after many hours working. I don't believe just because I have already spent hours on it and asked on stack, that I should simply give up trying.

Quote from my post at the link provided in the question...

> After working on this for quite a
>   while, what was missing was you needed
>   to add the action...
>
> `add_action('thematic_abovepost','childtheme_override_content_init');`
>
> I know it seems like you shouldn't
>   have to do this because on line 801
>   the add_action function is called...
>
> `add_action('thematic_abovepost','thematic_content_init');`
>
> However this is INSIDE the elseif
>   statment, and is only run if the child
>   override function does not exist.
>
> While my fix works, I propose that the
>   "add_action" line be moved outside of
>   the closing brace.

Comment: On the other hand, if anyone can suggest why my code change proposal is not the best way to fix this problem, please do.

Comment: After a while, I got a response on the official forum. Looks like there is a fix for this in the current head revision, but not yet deployed to the WP directory. This problem can be avoided by checking out the latest head revision. (At time of posting)

Answer (score 0):

If a `childtheme_override_content_init()` already exists in some other place, you can't 'override' it.

You can check if the function exists by adding this line of code in your single.php:

```
echo print_r(function_exists('childtheme_override_content_init()'))
```

If it prints TRUE the function exists, it won't work. In this case you have 2 options. Delete the original function or change it to behave as you expect.

Check out if the framework have any Hooks that can be used to modify the behavior of the function so you don't have to change or delete the original function.

Comment: Can confirm that the function doesn't already exist. Good idea though. Fresh child theme so it shouldn't have, and it doesn't.